# 0-1 Knapsack on infinite integer array?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

`Given an infinite positive integer array or say a stream of positive integers, find out the first five numbers whose sum is twenty.`

By reading the problem statement, it first seems to be `0-1 Knapsack` problem, but I am confused that can `0-1 Knapsack algo` be used on a stream of integers. Let suppose I write a recursive program for the above problem.

```
int knapsack(int sum, int count, int idx)
{
    if (sum == 0 && count == 0)
        return 1;

    if ((sum == 0 && count != 0) || (sum != 0 && count == 0))
        return 0;

    if (arr[idx] > 20) //element cann't be included.
        return knapsack(sum, count idx + 1);

    return max(knapsack(sum, count, idx +1), knapsack(sum - arr[idx], count -1, idx + 1));
}
```

Now when the above function will call on an infinite array, the first call in `max` function i.e. `knapsack(sum, count, idx +1)` will never return as it will keep on ignoring the current element. Even if we change the order of the call in `max` function, there is still possibility that the first call will never return. Is there any way to apply `knapsack` algo in such scenarios?

Comment: are you looking for the first five *consecutive* numbers whose sum is 20?

Comment: This is harder than the knapsack problem.  We have an additional constraint: we must find the earliest combination of numbers whose sum is twenty.  In other words, we must consider multiple knapsacks: the first 5 elements, then the first 6, then the first 7, etc.

Comment: @David: no... there is no such condition...

Comment: @cheeken You can find the earliest combination provided integers are positive. See my answer below.

Comment: @ElKamina: yes, integers are positive ... i will update the question.

Answer (score 5):

This works if you are working with only positive integers.

Basically keep a list of ways you can reach any of the first 20 numbers and whenever you process a new number process this list accordingly.

```
def update(dictlist, num):
    dk = dictlist.keys()
    for i in dk:
        if i+num <=20:
            for j in dictlist[i]:
                listlen = len(dictlist[i][j]) + 1
                if listlen >5:
                    continue
                if i+num not in dictlist or listlen not in dictlist[i+num]:
                    dictlist[i+num][listlen] = dictlist[i][j]+[num]
    if num not in dictlist:
        dictlist[num]= {}
    dictlist[num][1] = [num]
    return dictlist

dictlist = {}
for x in infinite_integer_stream:
    dictlist = update(dictlist,x)
    if 20 in dictlist and 5 in dictlist[20]:
        print dictlist[20][5]
        break
```

This code might have some minor bugs and I do not have time now to debug it. But basically dictlist[i][j] stores a j length list that sums to i.

Comment: Hmm, where are you imposing the 5-element constraint?

Comment: @cheeken I missed that part. The updated answer should handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi code:

```
var
  PossibleSums: array[1..4, 0..20] of Integer;
  Value, i, j: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  s := '';
  for j := 1 to 4 do
    for i := 0 to 20 do
      PossibleSums[j, i] := -1;
  while True do begin
    Value := 1 + Random(20); // stream emulation
    Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Value));

    if PossibleSums[4, 20 - Value] <> -1 then begin
    //we just have found 5th number to make the full sum
      s := IntToStr(Value);
      i := 20 - Value;
      for j := 4 downto 1 do begin
        //unwind storage chain
        s := IntToStr(PossibleSums[j, i]) + ' ' + s;
        i := i - PossibleSums[j, i];
      end;
      Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
      Break;
    end;

    for j := 3 downto 1 do
      for i := 0 to 20 - Value do
        if (PossibleSums[j, i] <> -1) and (PossibleSums[j + 1, i + Value] = -1) then
          PossibleSums[j + 1, i + Value] := Value;

    if PossibleSums[1, Value] = -1 then
      PossibleSums[1, Value] := Value;
  end;
end;
```

output:

```
4
8
9
2
10
2
17
2
4 2 10 2 2
```